# How to read a string as a long passed in JSON using Play framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am having problems writing a Reads for JSON passed from the client to the server.  The client always sends ids as Strings when they should be Numbers.  This causes issues when I try and Read them into a Scala object.  My case class expects them to be Long to match up with the DB but I am unsure how to read the String as Long.  I tried simply using .readNullable[Long] on employer_id but then it just returns validation errors that it expected a jsnumber.

Play-Scala 2.4.1

Scala 2.11.7

```
implicit val person_reads: Reads[Person] = (
    Reads.pure(-1L) and
    Reads.pure(None) and
    (JsPath \ "person" \ "given_name").readNullable[String](minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "person" \ "surname").readNullable[String](minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "person" \ "city").readNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "person" \ "state").readNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "person" \ "county").readNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "person" \ "zip").readNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "person" \ "country").readNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "person" \ "email").readNullable[String](email) and
    (JsPath \ "person" \ "phone").readNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "person" \ "employer_id").readNullable[String] and
    Reads.pure(Set[Long]()) and
    Reads.pure("") and
    Reads.pure("")
)(Person.apply _)

case class Person(
    id:Long, 
    facebook_id:Option[Long], 
    given_name:Option[String], 
    surname:Option[String], 
    city:Option[String], 
    state:Option[String], 
    county:Option[String], 
    zip:Option[String], 
    country:Option[String], 
    email:Option[String], 
    phone:Option[String], 
    employer_id:Option[Long], 
    people_connection_ids:Set[Long], 
    added:String, 
    modified:String
)
```

Example JSON POST/PUT

```
{
  "person": {
    "id": 78447,
    "facebook_id": 12345678987654321,
    "given_name": "Jon",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "county": "",
    "zip": "",
    "country": "",
    "email": "",
    "phone": "",
    "added": "",
    "modified": "",
    "employer_id": "1289592", <- This one gets passed as a string instead of number
    "people_connection_ids": [
      73
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @cchantep answer, in your case,

```
  (JsPath \ "person" \ "employer_id").readNullable[String].map(_.map{_.toLong}) and
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm choosing this as the correct answer as it was a drop in place answer.  I ended up using this in my code, `(JsPath \ "person" \ "employer_id").readNullable[String].map[Option[Long]](safeStringOptToLong(_)) and`  Because to me it reads better and I already had the safeStringToLong built and used throughout my app.

Answer (score 2):

You can `map` the read string as numeric.

```
(__ \ "id").read[String].map[Long](_.toLong)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I ended up building my answer from yours but I had to change parts to get it to work for me.  Because of that I chose @k.c. sham's answer as it matched my use case exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer using `play.api.libs.json`

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val js = """
       | {
       |   "person": {
       |     "id": 78447,
       |     "facebook_id": 12345678987654321,
       |     "given_name": "Jon",
       |     "surname": "Smith",
       |     "city": "",
       |     "state": "",
       |     "county": "",
       |     "zip": "",
       |     "country": "",
       |     "email": "",
       |     "phone": "",
       |     "added": "",
       |     "modified": "",
       |     "employer_id": "1289592",
       |     "people_connection_ids": [
       |       73
       |     ]
       |   }
       | }""".stripMargin

val json = Json.parse(js)

(json \ "person" \ "employer_id").asOpt[String].map(f => java.lang.Long.valueOf(f))
```

The output is

```
res0: Option[Long] = Some(1289592)
```